# Git clone error 'access rights' only on particular computer

Tags: git, git-clone

When I'm trying to clone git repository from my computer (Win 7) I receive an error 'Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.', but equivalent actions on computer (Win 7) of my colleague ends with succes. It must be said i have had cloned without problems the same repository on Virtual Machine (Ubuntu) installed on my computer. Please, help me to understand why this error appears only in case of Win 7 only on particular computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should check the URL with:
git remote -v

If it's correct, you have to be sure you are allowed to access the server from your IP, network and working group.

Git will raise that error in the case the URL is typed incorrectly or your computer is blocked by some firewall.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in Windows, see if you're logged in first with the following console commands (use Cygwin, not the Windows terminal) :

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

You need to be logged into a Git account with access rights to that repository. Use the same commands you'd use for UNIX but in Cygwin.

If you're using Github, there's a nice little GUI for it, as well as a UNIX-like terminal. The following download should install both.

http://windows.github.com/

Once you can "log in", click the grey checkbox next to this answer so that other people know it works.

Comment: I definitely have needed rights since I successfully cloned this repository from another computer 5 minutes ago. And problem is I can't do it from my computer.

Comment: What do you get when you try git config --global user.name and git config --global user.email from Windows, using a UNIX-like command line, e.g. Cygwin and not the Windows command line?

Comment: 1. I'm not trying to clone from github, but from our server (we just use git, not github). 2. when I try 'git config --global diziaq' I receive 'error: key does not contain a section: diziaq'. The same error I have in Ubuntu, where cloning passes without access errors.

Comment: The commands I gave will work on non-github git. If your username is correct, it could be a server-side permissions issue or your client could be blocking access to the server. Can you download other repositories from your server from that computer on Windows?

Comment: No, I can't. It clear for me that problem is in my client, may be it is blocking access, and I want to understand the reason of such behavior.

Comment: `user.name` is literal, so the command is `git config --global user.name`, not `git config --global diziaq`. If it still gives you an error then you're not logged in as diziaq on your Windows installation.

Comment: 'git config --global user.name' gives nothing, it only goes to new command prompt

Comment: That means you aren't "logged in" on your Widows machine. It should print out your username. Did you use Cygwin or the Windows command line?

Comment: That means you aren't "logged in" on your Widows machine. It should print out your username. When I run `git config --global user.name` from a UNIX terminal, it returns `JaneGoodall` and it should do the same in Cygwin.

Comment: I've printed it into unix terminal in ubuntu. And I didn't get what  do you mean by 'not logged in': is it about not logged in OS or in Git. Anyway, it seems to me we, go in wrong direction, I guess problems may be in my Windows 7 settings.